# what does the phrase "we see through you like it's glass" mean?

Tags: sentence-meaning

What does the phrase: "We see through you like it's glass" mean? could you explain, please?

Comment: We need more context.  You can "see through" something that is made of glass.  But "see through" has other figurative meanings, which you should find in a dictionary.  You should look that up before asking the question.

Comment: "See through you" is an idiom.  Look it up.

Comment: This is one of those similes in English that use two different meanings of a word (or a phrase, in this case). The canonical example is *he lies like a rug*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Person A says to person B: "We see through you like it's glass" 
That means person A thinks that she (and a group of people she belongs to (or she's royalty and refers to herself as 'we')) can easily see the motives (especially ulterior motives) that person B has for doing something.

Comment: I think I understand now, so It means " We have your number clearly", isn't it?

Comment: It means approximately 'we have you figured out', 'we have your number', 'we know what you are up to', 'we know your true colors', ...